# h ref attribute issue for page navigation on Word Press

Tags: wordpress, href

I have a pretty basic question. I am using an "h ref" attribute to make a page searchable on my Word Press site. It is a Shakespeare play and I want to be able to click on a contents link to go to specific act/scene. I am using the following code:

```
<span style="color: #000000;"> <a href="#line-1.1.0">Act 1, Scene 1</a></span>
```

Which links to:

```
<span id="line-SD 1.1.0" title="SD 1.1.0">with</span><span id="line-SD 1.1.0" 
title="SD 1.1.0"> Musicians playing.</span>
```

When I click on the link on the live page it goes to the start of the specificity scene; however, when I try to scroll from that scene, I am taken back to the beginning of the play.  Any help is much appreciated.

[Screen Shot of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBV2G.png)

Comment: You must have something else that's causing this, maybe some scrolling plugin or Javascript.

Comment: I'm using column shortcode to make the play text scrollable while a left-hand column with the search field is static.